# header jump to the middle of screen (JqueryMobile)

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

i'm working at .NET application using JQMobile
i have a fixed header on the page , my problem is on blur action of textbox the header jump to the middle of the screen.any body know how can i solve this issue?

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Header</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: code will not help at any more this is a global issue and i have search for it and no one solve it till now !! look at this https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1087

Comment: also happens sometimes when displaying the "loading" animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to adding `position: absolute` to the header then edit it to `fixed`

Comment: do you mean add position:absolute in the style tag ?

Comment: yes, add position:absolute then change it to fixed by using jQuery.